# SwiftUI DispatchQueue Button

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I don't understand the issues around how SwiftUI and DispatchQueues work. Here is the code.

This works and will continue to refresh the counter state variable every second.

```
// Example 1 - This works
struct TimerButtonTest : View {
    @State var counter: Int = 0
    var body: some View {        
        start()
        return VStack { Text("\(counter)") }
    }

    func start() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(1000)) {
            self.counter += 1
        }
    }
}
```

This does not. After the button is pressed, the counter increments by 1 (after 1 second) but stops.

```
// Example 2 - This does not work
struct TimerButtonTest : View {
    @State var counter: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        return Button(action: {self.start()}, label: {Text("\(counter)")})
    }

    func start() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(1000)) {
            self.counter += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the counter continue incrementing like the first example?

Comment: @Paulw11 Already pointed the problem in your code, you may check condition that if counter != 0 then call the start manually above your return statement or may you can have another state var to know weather counter starts or not and act accordingly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first piece of code you call `start` each time the `body` of the button is evaluated.

`start` (eventually) updates `counter` which is the state that is bound to the button's `Text`.  Updating the bound state causes SwiftUI to evaluate the `body` var again.  This calls `start`, which calls the `asyncAfter` and the process repeats indefinitely.  As Rob pointed out in the comments, this isn't a very good approach - `body` might be called at any time and any number of times, so you can't guarantee that you will only get an update once per second.

In the second piece of code you only call `start` when the button is tapped.  `counter` will be updated after a second and the `Text` updated. Nothing further will happen until you tap the button again.

Comment: Note that you should **not** call `start` in `body`. SwiftUI can call ask for your `body` property at any time, and any number of times.

Comment: I agree, that is a sketchy approach. You should probably create a **@BindableObject** external to the view, which implements the timer. Every time the bindable object updates its counter, your view will pick it up, invalidate and refresh its body.